# Way to access Array with jQuery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dom

i've got an array like following

```
[jQuery('div#example1'), jQuery('div#example2'), jQuery('div#example3'), jQuery('div#etcetera')]
```

Goal

```
elementArray = [jQuery('div#example1'), jQuery('div#example2'), jQuery('div#example3'), jQuery('div#etcetera')];

$(elementArray).remove();

//or

$(elementArray).css('border', '1px solid red');
```

I want them all to get the same treatment, with some function. The only way i know to access the elements is to loop trough the array.

Can someone help me out with a more efficient way to go about this?

Comment: `jQuery(div#wallItem303.wallItem✉)` should be `jQuery('div#wallItem303.wallItem✉')` - you're missing quotes.

Comment: @sime Error in the example, copied from firebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$.each(elementArray, function(i, v) {
    v.remove();
});
```

When using `$.each`, the function runs for every array element (which is referenced by `v`).

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/XyRZE/

---

*Update:* You could use `map` to replace each jQuery object in the array with the DOM element object that's contained within it.

```
$(elementArray).map(function(i, v) { return v[0]; }).remove();
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/XyRZE/1/

Comment: as i stated in the question. I know how to access the array in a loop. My question is if there's a more efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could select the items all together to one jQuery array

```
var myArray = $("div#wallItem303.wallItem, div#wallItem103.wallItem, div#wallItem323.wallItem");
myArray.css('border', '1px solid red');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can target multiple elements in a jquery selector.

See [jQuery multiple selector api](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/).

```
jQuery('#wallItem303, #wallItem303').remove();
```

N.B if you have an id do not prefix it with the nodeName in the selector.

Comment: that would work, except the array exists of jQuery objects, not selector strings. I need to use this array.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution.
The way you did is fine, however if you want to use a function, here you have:

```
$(elementArray).each(function(){
   $(this).css('border', '1px solid red');
   //Do whatever you want in this function
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: as i stated in the question. I know how to access the array in a loop. My question is if there's a more efficient way.